# How can I detect the green region (meter display) & crop it out using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, detection, region

I want to extract the green region (meter display) from an image. Here I have attached an image which is digital electric meter. I want to extract only the region which contains the meter reading value. If I only detect the green region then other green regions are also detected, but I want to detect only the green region which contains meter reading. How can I do that in MATLAB ?

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
Im = imread('2.jpg');
Im = imresize(Im, [512 512]);
diff_im = imsubtract(Im(:,:,2),rgb2gray(Im));
figure,imshow(diff_im);
```

[image: Raw image]

Answer (score 1):

Just binarize the result:

```
binary = imbinarize(diff_im, 25/255); % optimal threshold would be between 22 and 25
figure,imshow(binary);
```

You can also play with morphological operations afterwards, e.g. morphological opening to remove leftovers of other areas.

Comment: i dnt understand whu u do binarize and why u set threshold 25/255. please explain

Comment: I binarize your diff_im image, and I use 25/255 threshold because as you can read in Matlab docs, imbinarize() always expect the threshold to be within the range [0;1], and diff_im has values in the range [0;255]

Comment: but when i take another image... it not works in u r code. why ?

Comment: Can't say for sure without  seeing this image, but probably illumination, exposure time etc. is different. Maybe you need to normalize the image and choose the threshold based on normalized values.